# Installing Cordova Plugin Purchase and using it with Google Play Developer Console

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins, android-billing

I am using the [Cordova Plugin Purchase](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase) in my Cordova project.  I have tried installing it using Cordova CLI 5.1 and now 6.0.0. I have added my billing key from the developer console in two locations just to see if one worked.  Added it to the fetch.json as a variable

```
"cc.fovea.cordova.purchase": {
    "source": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase.git",
        "subdir": "."
    },
    "is_top_level": true,
  "variables": {
    "BILLING_KEY": "MY_KEY"
  }
```

and to the config.xml

```
 <plugin name="cc.fovea.cordova.purchase" version="4.0.0" src="https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase.git">
<param name="BILLING_KEY" value="MY_KEY" />
```

Also, in my AndroidManifest.xml I added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

I have followed the steps located on the [setup and help](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/wiki/HOWTO#setup-android-applications) screens at the plugins site, but I have still not been able to upload an APK which adds the billing permission.  When uploaded it does not say there are any new added permissions and even if I click save anyway and then navigate to the In-app Products tab I still get the message saying, "To add in-app products, you need to add the BILLING permission to your APK."

I have read thru many questions on stack overflow and on the web, but I feel like I am missing a step somewhere.  Any ideas or more detailed walk thru's that I might be missing?

**Update**:
I have updated to Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova 6 and tried to re-install the package.  Still no billing permission and when I try to add it myself nothing happens....

Comment: Hi, did you solve the problem?

Comment: I thought I had using https://alexdisler.com/2016/02/29/in-app-purchases-ionic-cordova/  but this did not have subscriptions working properly.  I am still at a loss trying to get the above to work.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same, and it's working fine on PlayStore with Cordova CLI 5.4 + VS2015, I will add my configuration here later (I dont have access to them right now)

Comment: I went ahead and downgraded the CLI to 5.4 which actually forced me to re-install all my plugins which was annoying however, this did allow me to enter the billing key and it actually register.  I am still interested in seeing your configuration though because when I call the store object it is undefined.  I also updated the project back to 6.0 and the billing key still works just the store object remains undefined

Comment: In Config.xml I have this line `  <plugin name="cc.fovea.cordova.purchase" version="4.0.0" />` no billing key.
Then in Plugins folder in `Fetch.json` file I have this:
    "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase": {
        "source": {
            "type": "registry",
            "id": "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase"
        },
        "is_top_level": true,
        "variables": {
            "BILLING_KEY": "MyBillingKey"
        }
    },

Comment: I tried that since I had not tried my registry version, but just gave me the billing key is missing error.  Even put it in the config.xml.  I am stumped on this one.  Might just go back to the other plugin since they are fixing the subscription issue.  If you think of anything else random you did let me know, if not it must just be something with my machine/environment......  Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many attempts and hours wasted I switched to a different plugin that has been very easy to install and work with.  The only downside as of now is that it does not support windows phone.  I could use one that works on all, but this was very easy to set up.  I know this does not truly answer my question on the above plugin, but it was the best route I found for now.  Below are the links to the location on github and Alex's blog site for more instructions.

[Cordova Plugin InAppPurchase](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase)

[Alex Disler Blog](https://alexdisler.com/2016/02/29/in-app-purchases-ionic-cordova/)

*UPDATE*  6/10

After I saw the update for Visual Studio Apache Cordova 10 was released I decided I would attempt this one more time..... And it now works.  They even give you the ability to add parameters which is why I assume it works.  Still not sure why it might have worked for others, but either way if you have the same trouble just update to CLI 6.2.0

[Apache Cordova Release 10](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release-update-10/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Visual Studio, but I found on plugin's website this tip: https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/blob/master/doc/windows.md#building-source-on-windows

"After adding the plugin to the config.xml in Visual Studio. If you receive an error about a missing BILLING_KEY parameter. Add the following into your config.xml:"

```
<vs:plugin name="cc.fovea.cordova.purchase" version="4.0.0" src="https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase.git">
  <param name="BILLING_KEY" value="YOUR GOOGLE BILLING KEY HERE TO TARGET ANDROID" />
</vs:plugin>
```

and it worked for me also for andoird.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out in a week.  Going to be too busy before then.  I never tried my iOS implementation.  Did they all work for you after installing them this way?  And I suppose you would have to do the same type of install for it even though its not listed?

Comment: I attempted the building source on windows part to no avail.  I even went ahead and tried to bower the product in and still no luck.  I had already added the billing key parameter before which did not work.....  Just going to use a different plugin.  thanks!